# Using Google Analytics in Cocoapods unable

Tags: ios, google-analytics, cocoapods

I just follow the link below to add the Google Analytics into my project.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/

But when I used the **pod update** in my project

I got following result

[image]

Can anyone help me with this?

-------------edit---------

pod 'GoogleAnalytics' is good

but I think it lose something compare with pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'

I'm not sure if it cause any effect

But I found the answer
just replace ios,'6.0' by ios,'7.0'

Answer (score 2):

Try this, Open the Podfile replace the following line

```
pod 'Google/Analytics', '~> 1.0.0'
```

by this line

```
pod 'GoogleAnalytics'
```

Save the file and run:

```
pod install
```

References - https://cocoapods.org/pods/GoogleAnalytics